# I want to make line art clear

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

I made a building background and it's part of it

The camera just changed the angle and showed the view

Line art won't come out properly.

[image]

The lines are merged into one where I are marked

I feel tired when I see the lines coming together and separating over and over again.

I tried rendering it at 8k resolution, but it didn't work

Zooming in in viewport mode makes the line neat, but rendering makes the line ugly.

I turned off and on the Line Art option, but I couldn't find anything effective.

[image]

Comment: are u sure that this isn't only happening because of line thickness? you decide how thick the line should be and if it is "too thick" then two lines will overlap if they are near to each other...here is my "first shot" with thinner lines: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmMDF.gif

Comment: The reason for thickening the line is to make it similar to the thickness of the character line. It's weird if the background is thin but the character lines are thick. I'm going to draw the character myself. Thinning the line helps to print it out, but I want to keep it this thick. Thank you for your answer